# Java - I can't write a string to a file if the string begins with "<"

Tags: java, file, io, output

If I use the following code:

```
try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
              new FileOutputStream(fileName), "utf-8"));


        writer.write("<title>");




    } catch (IOException e) {

      throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {

       try {
           writer.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }

    }
```

nothing shows up in the file, but if I remove the "<" , and try to output "title>" it works fine. How can I get around this?

Comment: really - what is your filename?

Comment: Seems to be working for me. What's your JDK version?

Comment: How do you check the file for its content?

Comment: Use writer.close() method.

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis he calls writer.close() in the finally block

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in your code, it's in the viewer (editor) that you're using to view the output. Instead of showing you the plain plain text, it's interpreting the data in the file, and showing you its interpretation. Use a plain editor such as notepad or vi to see what is in the file.

Answer (score -1):

Try flushing your writer after you write:

```
writer.write("<title>");
writer.flush();
```

Comment: so why would he not need to flush if not using `<`?

Comment: Whether or not the writer will flush by itself is kinda random. Flushing it gives you more control and 'might' solve the problem.